# Linear Algebra Analytical Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

This one has me stumped...

$$H=C(sI-A)^{-1}B$$

and

$$H_{CL} = C(sI-A+BK)^{-1}BG$$

Show that $$H_{CL} = H[I+K(sI-A))^{-1}B]^{-1}G$$

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Amzoti It's from a Control Theory text book. The context is basically irrelevant, since it's just an analytical linear algebra exercise.

Comment: @Amzoti H: open-loop transfer function, Hcl: closed-loop transfer function, x_dot = Ax + B (open-loop), x_dot = (A-BK)x + BGr where K is a constant state feedback gain, G: gain, r: reference input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
Z:=(sI-A)^{-1}.
$$
Then $H =CZB$, and 
$$
H_{CL}=C(Z^{-1}+BK)^{-1}BG.
$$
The claim is:
$$ 
H_{CL} = C(Z^{-1}+BK)^{-1}BG \stackrel!=H(I+KZB)^{-1}G =CZB(I+KZB)^{-1}G ,
$$
thus it suffices to prove
$$
(Z^{-1}+BK)^{-1}B = ZB(I+KZB)^{-1}.
$$

Since $(I+BA)^{-1} = I - B(I+AB)^{-1}A$, it follows
$$
\begin{split}
(Z^{-1}+BK)^{-1}B &= ( Z^{-1}(I+ZBK))^{-1}B 
\\&=(I+ZBK)^{-1}ZB
\\&=(I-ZB(I+KZB)^{-1}K)ZB
\\&= ZB(I-(I+KZB)^{-1}KZB)
\\&=ZB(I-(I+KZB)^{-1}(I+KZB-I))
\\&= ZB(I-I+(I+KZB)^{-1}) 
\\&= ZB(I+KZB)^{-1},
\end{split}$$
which proves the claim.

To see $(I+BA)^{-1} = I - B(I+AB)^{-1}A$, calculate
$$
\begin{split}
(I+BA)(I - B(I+AB)^{-1}A) &= I - B(I+AB)^{-1}A + BA - BAB(I+AB)^{-1}A\\
&= I+BA - B(I+AB)(I+AB)^{-1}A\\&=I.
\end{split}
$$